# How can I tell if a Pokémon will have a higher CP when evolved than a currently evolved Pokémon of the same type?

Tags: pokemon-go

I caught a Squirtle with 332 CP but the bar is almost full. I also have a Blastoise (Squirtle's final evolution) with 764 CP and the bar is almost full as well.

How can I tell if my Squirtle would have a higher CP then my Blastoise after I evolve my Squirtle?

Answer (score 3):

This is a good question. I actually had a very similar situation when choosing to continue saving candy for a Nidoran or to go ahead and evolve the Nidorina.

CP is directly correlated and determined by the individual values, or IVs, of your specific Pokemon. To figure out what those IVs are, you have a few options to figure this one out.

1. You could use the appraisal feature built into the game as of a previous update, roughly a month ago. This will give you a general idea of how high your Pokemon's IVs are. I generally use this to weed out objectively weak Pokemon before using the other method.
2. You can get the exact IVs of your specific Pokemon by using an IV calculator, such as the ones found [here](https://thesilphroad.com/research) or [here](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator).

Once you know how your Pokemon stack up IV-wise, you have to decide whether it is worth training a lower-CP Pokemon with near-perfect IVs or going along with a decently-high-CP Pokemon with lower IVs. In the end, the higher IV Pokemon will have higher CP, but it will take more time to get there.

Comment: I personally like this one here: https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator. If you enter what the in-game appraisal tells you, it almost always nails down the exact IV's of your Pokemon. It's much easier to use than trying to make sure that you match the CP arc between the webapp and your Pokemon in-game.

Comment: @Ellesedil I used to use that one but when tracking was removed and Pokevision was taken down, it seemed to stop working for me so I stopped using it. Does it work now? Trying to get the right numbers on the slider bar on my phone is a nightmare, so an alternative would be awesome

Comment: Sure does work. Give it a try. Make sure you pay attention to the checkboxes and drop-down on the right. Entering what stats the game appraises for you makes it really accurate.

Comment: @Ellesedil awesome, I'll add that link to my answer as well.

Answer (score -2):

All of the same pokemon will have the same maximum CP given the same trainer level. What you do want to look at however are the hidden IV stats as well as the movesets.

There is an IV calculator [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wbtIc33K45iU1ScUnkB0PlslJ-eLaJlSZY47sPME2Uk/copy).

Comment: they have IV stats in Pokemon GO?

Comment: Yea, just do a simple google search or just look at /r/SilphRoad.